# In self-hosted OWIN Web API, how to run code at shutdown?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am self-hosting a OWIN Web API using these code snippets:

```
class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        var route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "{controller}");
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}

WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:8080")
```

I would like to run some code when my Web API service shuts down. I'm looking for something like `HttpApplication.Application_End`, a `Disposed` event, or a well-placed `override void Dispose()`.

How do I run code when the Web API service shuts down?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This can be achieved by getting the host's cancelation token and registering a callback with it like so

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var context = new OwinContext(app.Properties);
        var token = context.Get<CancellationToken>("host.OnAppDisposing");
        if (token != CancellationToken.None)
        {
            token.Register(() =>
            {
                // code to run
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I was told by someone on the Katana team that this key is for host specific functionality and therefore may not exist on all hosts. [Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/) does implement this, but I'm not sure about the others.

The easiest way to verify if this will work for you is to check `app.Properties` for the `host.OnAppDisposing` key.

Comment: @Wally: It would be great if you explain how to test it.

Comment: To test it, dispose the result of the WebApp<Startup>() call and watch the code in the token.Register() action execute..

Comment: The `if (token != CancellationToken.None)` is a little redundant, CancellationToken.None.Register(action) does the check and returns an empty CancellationTokenRegistration() for non-cancellable tokens. You can do a one-liner: `new AppProperties(app.Properties).OnAppDisposing.Register(() => { /* stuff */ });`

Comment: You are such a ninja!

Answer (score 70):

I think there is a better way to get the `CancellationToken`:

```
var properties = new AppProperties(app.Properties);
CancellationToken token = properties.OnAppDisposing;
```

`AppProperties` is under namespace `Microsoft.Owin.BuilderProperties`, which comes from this nuget package: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin/

The description of property `OnAppDisposing` says:

Gets or sets the cancellation token for “host.OnAppDisposing”.

Please refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.builderproperties.appproperties%28v=vs.113%29.aspx

Comment: What do you do with the instance of `properties`?

Comment: You can throw it away, it is just a wrapper around `app.Properties`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as arthas's answer but I've made it into an extension method

```
public static IAppBuilder RegisterShutdown(this IAppBuilder app, Action callback)
{
    if (app == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
    }

    var properties = new AppProperties(app.Properties);
    var token = properties.OnAppDisposing;

    if (token != CancellationToken.None)
    {
        token.Register(callback);
    }

    return app;
}
```

Because then you can easily register shutdown actions like this

```
app.RegisterShutdown(() => Serilog.Log.CloseAndFlush());
```